# play 6 channels audio Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, psychtoolbox, surround

I want to play 6 sounds on the same time on 6 channels. (I have a logiLink and i plug 3 cables  Front, Surround , Bass/Center ). I don't know how to do it.
From what I looked on google I can do it with data acquisition toolbox ( but I dont have money), with Playrec or with PsychToolbox 
 This information I found it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736049/output-4-channels-of-audio-in-matlab)

What I am asking you is to recommend me what to use  and to point me to some documentation about the software you will recommend.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you after as an end result? To play audio with 6 channels? Or you want to combine them into a single channel?

Comment: [Use VLC?](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)

Comment: to play audio with 6 channels . instead of headphones with 2 outputs for each ear i have some headphones with 6 outputs , and i want to play 6 diffrent songs on each output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my device didn't have ASIO so I installed ASIO4ALL and eveything worked fine